# encrypted_strings (LoadError) received when running spotify ruby script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, spotify

I am trying to run a Ruby script to setup a token exchange with spotify. I know nothing about Ruby, so am at a loss at how to resolve the following error in response to the following command:

```
ruby ./spotify_token_swap.rb
/Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-dev/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- encrypted_strings (LoadError)
    from /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-dev/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from ./spotify_token_swap.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Line 54 of kernel_require.rb is:

```
return gem_original_require(path)
```

If it helps, here is my RubyGems environment:

```
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5-dev
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-dev/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5-dev/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/jeff/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5-dev
     - /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5-dev@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5-dev/bin
     - /Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5-dev@global/bin
     - /Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-dev/bin
     - /Users/jeff/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/ImageMagick/bin
```

I am guessing that there is either a missing gem, or a problem with my path. But I really don't know. Can someone provide some handholding on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Sorry someone downvoted your question.  It seems like a good question to me.  +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good debugging idea, but you went a bit too deep :)  You don't need to know *how* [`Kernel.require`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-require) works, just that

> If the file named cannot be found, a LoadError will be raised.

You probably just need to install the [encrypted_strings](https://rubygems.org/gems/encrypted_strings) gem.

Comment: I tried the following, but it did not work. Is this the wrong syntax: gem encrypted_strings
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command encrypted_strings

Comment: Close, you're using the right tool, namely `gem`.  If you don't know how to use a command, use the unix manual: `man gem`.  There you will find the correct syntax to install a gem.

Comment: ok, thanks. "gem install encrypted_strings" fixed the problem